# Can't seem to get runningvalues to work in VS2013 Report Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I have a margins report that I've created that groups by Month, Customer, Sales Type then displays the sales details.  I have that basic report working well.  The SALTYPE group has four options from the stored procedure that pulls the data, they are A, B, C, D.  I've been asked to add grand totals at the bottom of the report for each sales type.

From my research it appears I need to use RunningValues in an expression to generate these totals but I've been unable to find any useful examples.  I've tested for the Tot. Sales column using the expression =RunningValue(Fields!TOTSALES.value, sum, "SALTYPE") but it throws an error I'm not sure I'm interpreting correctly, "The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox168' has a scope parameter that is not valid for the aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset".  If I understand correctly it's referring to "Tablix1_SALTYPEGroup" but I'm unclear what that should be or if I'm completely off base.

Can anyone provide an example to get those grand totals or point out the flaw in my expression?  I've been all through MSDN but primarily been referencing [this blog](https://blog.stevienova.com/2007/07/02/ssrs-runningvalue-to-get-cumulative-totals/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I may be incorrect but it appears they way I had my groups structured and the details sorted it wasn't possible to generate the totals I needed.  I resolved this by simply adding a summary Tablix below my first one, using the same data but structured and sorted in a way to easily generate my totals.  By sorting the details on the SALTYPE I could then just add a total and hide the details.  The result is exactly what I was looking for.

[image]